# How do you remove leading 0 before decimal in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I know this is probably a simple fix and there's many posts on here, but after looking through many of them I can't get it to work.

I am running a mySQL query to return batting average for a baseball player:

```
SELECT playerID, ROUND(H/AB,3) AS 'AVG'
FROM Batting
WHERE playerID = 'troutmi01'
```

When I run that it returns

```
troutmi01   0.220
troutmi01   0.326
troutmi01   0.323
```

However, I would like it to return

```
troutmi01   .220
troutmi01   .326
troutmi01   .323
```

Comment: This is not calculation problem, this is output problem. Format values as you need on the client side. *However, I would like it to return* - you must understand that the datatype of output will be string, not numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TRIM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function:

```
SELECT playerID, TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM ROUND(H/AB,3)) AS 'AVG'
FROM Batting
WHERE playerID = 'troutmi01'
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't try that one out first. Works perfectly, Thank you.